# Hide/Unhide button if checkbox is ticked in access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

There are 4 check-boxes and if any of the 2 check-boxes (checkA & checkB) is checked then the button "Justification" shouldn't be visible on the form. Likewise, if any of the other 2 check-boxes (checkC & checkD) is checked then the button "justification" should be visible.

And, there is a combo box (Combo380) which is a drop down with a macro code:

```
="[ID] = " & Str(Nz([Screen].[ActiveControl],0))
```

Lastly, i cannot use on click or afterupdate event for checkbox and nor can i use If VBA code which will give run time error no. 2427. I can only use GotFocus or LostFocus event.

Here is my formula:

```
Private Sub CheckA_GotFocus()
    Me.Justification.Visible = False
End Sub
Private Sub CheckB_GotFocus()
    Me.Justification.Visible = False
End Sub
Private Sub CheckC_GotFocus()
    Me.Justification.Visible = True
End Sub
Private Sub CheckD_GotFocus()
    Me.Justification.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Can someone please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you use `AfterUpdate`?  If it already contains code, surely you can just add a single line near the start that will change the visibility of the control that was updated?  Why does an `IF` command raise a `Argument not optional` error?  Have you tried reinstalling Access if you get those results?

Comment: You should be using the `AfterUpdate` event. If you are getting an error in the `AfterUpdate` event, please post the code you tried.

Comment: Do you have code in place not to allow all check boxes to have the same state at the same time?

Comment: `Me.Justification.Visible = Me.CheckC Or Me.CheckD` As already noted, your setup presents conflict if CheckA or CheckB can be checked as well as CheckC or CheckD. Perhaps you should be using radio buttons in an OptionGroup control. Need to know more about data to advise. What has combobox to do with this?

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook & @ArcherBird: I used "Option Group" (from the Design tab) to create Check-boxes, So, the `AfterUpdate` event doesn't appear. Secondly, if i use "IF" statement then i'll get run time error 2427. Which says the check-box doesn't have any value. And, if i use `If isnul(me.CheckA)` then this doesn't work............

Comment: Combo box is a drop down list, when selected it'll change the data on screen.

Comment: @June7 as said above `me.checkC` gives a runtime error 2427. It says the value is null. So i must use `isnull or not isnull` code

Comment: I added 4 checkboxes and button with same names and copy/pasted your code. No errors. Even tried checkboxes set for triple state. Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: I changed the entire code and now it's working great:

Comment: `Dim m_Justify As Boolean

Private Sub Justification_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Justification Skill Competency", acNormal, , _
    "[Critical Skill Name]=" & "'" & [Critical Skill Name] & "'"
       
End Sub

Private Sub Frame289_Click()
    Select Case Me.Frame289
    
    Case 1
    m_Justify = False
       
    Case 2
    m_Justify = False
        
    Case 3
    m_Justify = True
        
    Case 4
    m_Justify = True
    End Select`

Comment: `If m_Justify = True Then
            Me.Justification.Visible = True
    ElseIf m_Justify = False Then
            Me.Justification.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: Could you edit your question and add that to it rather than as a comment, or if it's the answer then add it as an answer so you can mark it as accepted - the question won't keep appearing as unanswered then.

Comment: The `Afterupdate` event for the `Option Group` can be found in the frame that you place the `Option Buttons` in.  Can't remember the syntax, etc offhand but clicking an option button in an option group creates an event on the frame rather than the button.